# highlight all class when one of the class member is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
*HTML
<div id='board'>
    <div>abc<span class='curly1'>{</span></div>
    <div>'jkl'm<span class='curly2'>{</span>no<span class='curly2'>}</span></div>
    <div><span class='curly2'>}</span></div>
</div>
```

This is for my code editor project, i want to achieve something like a notepad++ feature, highlighting the paired braces like {}, (), [], '', "". How will you say this in css,js or using jquery?

The logic is to have something like this:

```
$(.curly1).hover(function(){
    //all class under curly1.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think there is an error in you html.

```
...
   <div><span class='curly2'>}</span></div>
</div>
```

will be

```
...
   <div><span class='curly1'>}</span></div>
</div>
```

Please try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#board").on("mouseenter mouseover", "[class^=curly]", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        $("." + className).addClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
    $("#board").on("mouseleave mouseout", "[class^=curly]", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        $("." + className).removeClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
});
```

and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/).

And, My suggestion is change class to data property, looks like

```
<div>abc<span data-class='curly1'>{</span></div>
```

then change the javascript like

```
var className = $(this).attr('data-class');
```

---

If the curly thing are just for left and right brace.
The codes would be looks like. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/1/)

```
*HTML
<div id='board'>
    <div>
        abc<span data-class='curly1'>{</span>
        <div>
            'jkl'm<span data-class='curly1'>{</span>no<span data-class='curly2'>}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            'jkl'm<span data-class='curly1'>{</span>
            <div>
                'jkl'm<span data-class='curly1'>{</span>no<span data-class='curly2'>}</span>
            </div>
            <span data-class='curly2'>}</span>
        </div>
        <span data-class='curly2'>}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I changed the logic to 
1. find the paired brace.
2. change their css both.

Here are the codes

```
*javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#board").on("mouseenter mouseover", "[data-class^=curly]", function() {
            var nodes = $(this).add(findPair($(this)));
            nodes.addClass("curlyHighlight");
        });
        $("#board").on("mouseleave mouseout", "[data-class^=curly]", function() {
            var nodes = $(this).add(findPair($(this)));
            nodes.removeClass("curlyHighlight");
        });
    });

    function findPair(n) {

        var nextBraces = $([]);
        var brace = n.text();
        if (brace == '{') {
            nextBraces = n.nextAll("[data-class^=curly]");
        } else if (brace == '}') {
            nextBraces = n.prevAll("[data-class^=curly]");
        }

        var count = 0;
        var result = false;
        nextBraces.each(function(index, value) {
            var v = $(value);
            if (v.text() == brace) {
                count++;
            } else if (count != 0) {
                count--;
            } else {
                result = v;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, 3 curly2 and only one curly1 in the HTML. Probably needs to be 2 of each, though I'm not sure which is supposed to be curly 1s - my guess is that all { are curly1, and all } are curly2 - as if they are only to match the other brace, you would need classes for every single pair of braces.

Comment: @AngelWarrior I presume the number is identification of paired braces. ^O^;

Comment: Yes, I gathered. :) You may be right as that would look more useful to a user, but I sure wouldn't want to have to code that with a ton of nested braces!

Comment: @AngelWarrior I made some changes in that case. Please take a look. Wait ! you are NOT the guy who asked this question. >"<

Comment: Sorry, no, I didn't intend for you to think I was the OP. I was just agreeing originally that 3 curly2 must be wrong, and wondering what the OP really wanted.

Comment: That's fine, I had my fun anyway. ^O^. And i ageree your opion that all { are curly1, and all } are curly2. That makes sense. I will do the same thing too.

Comment: im ok with the first one, im avoiding loop as much as possible for speedy result. Salamat

Comment: @Clxy the hover is not enough when the user of my system will scroll down the contenteditable div to find the paired braces. What do you suggest?

Comment: @fireflieslive How about change the event to click.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/4/)

Comment: how about the unclick equiv sir?

Comment: one last thing, can you please modify this: [class^=curly] because i realized that after some time the class name will not just be curly1, curly2.. etc.. but 'something curly1', 'somewhatever curly2' 'someahsof curly3'

Comment: 1.unclick is unnecessary as you probably already know. 2.Please take a look at [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), so you can write exactly what you want.My suggestion is put this curly thing into other property like I mentioned above. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/5/)

Comment: I pursue doing the first logic because of my design. anyway, i have no success with having a span with two classes http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/10/

Comment: class='bm1' should be data-class='bm1'...then,you can use data-class identify the braces.http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/16/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/haoudoin/rzp6b/

Assuming that you are generating the curls dynamically and that you are able to keep count of the curls,  I recommend using a combination of ID's and CSS Classes along with a numbering system, to give it some semantics and grouping.  It will also help us with the DOM manipulation.  So, here is the my recommended HTML:

```
    <div id='board'>
        <div>public class MyObject()<span id='open-curly1' class='curly curly1'>{</span>
        </div>
        <div>public void setKey()<span id='open-curly2' class='curly curly2'>{</span>return true;<span id='close-curly2' class='curly curly2'>}</span></div>
        <div>public void setValue()<span id='open-curly3' class='curly curly3'>{</span>return true;<span id='close-curly3' class='curly curly3'>}</span></div>
        <div><span id='close-curly1' class='curly curly1'>}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the hover class for your CSS:

```
    .hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Here is the voodoo magic in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get the curls
    var $curls = $("#board .curly");
    console.log($curls.length);
    // get the number of match & unmatched curls (Math.ceil)
    var curlyCount = Math.ceil($curls.length / 2);
    console.log(curlyCount);
    // systematically add a hover to each pair of matched curls and the unmatched
    for (var i = 1; i <= curlyCount; i++) {
        addCurlyHover(".curly" + i);
    }
});

function addCurlyHover (curlyClass) {
    // get the closing and opening curl, because they have a common class name
    // for example: .curly1
    $(curlyClass, "#board").hover(function (event) {
        // console.log(curlyClass);
        // will look for curly spans every time,in case braces are removed or added and reference is lost
        $(curlyClass).each(function (index) {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        });
    }, function (event) {
        // console.log(curlyClass);
        $(curlyClass).each(function (index) {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: the `$("#board " + curlyClass)` can become `$(curlyClass, "#board")`. The #board will act as the context

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  It happens to be my first ever on Stack... LOL

@Harsh Good call, less string manipulation the better I suppose.  Updated the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a unique class for all block delimiters (e.g. `delimiter`) and then another attribute to store their match (e.g. `data-match`).

So the [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html)s would be like:

```
<span class="delimiter" data-match="7">
```

And in the JavaScript:

```
$('.delimiter').hover(function () {
    var match = $(this).attr('data-match');

    $('.delimiter').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-match') === match) {
            // Do your styling here. Maybe add a class to the element.
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, this is much cleaner and logical solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how jquery works, but if the second $('.delimiter') takes time to find the elements, and gets called on every hover, it would be faster if you could store that list as a var outside the present code.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but on hover on any .curly1 element, in javascript you could grab all the .curly1 elements and add another class to them, the second class would be the highlighting class. On mouseout, remove the second class from all the .curly1 elements.

Using YUI, it looks like this:

```
var curlyNodes = Y.all('.curly1');
curlyNodes.on('mouseenter', function(){
    curlyNodes.addClass('highlight');
});
curlyNodes.on('mouseleave', function(){
    curlyNodes.removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: I don't use jquery, so I'm not sure of the proper syntax there. But you probably want a second class name with the css: .highlight{background-color:red;}  I'm sure that jquery has a way of adding and removing classes by name. You'll also need to have a way to remove the class when hover is done.